# Is there any solution to calculate data from DataFrame pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> type of data_frame
> There are 85 something columns and 800+ rows data frame look like this

> for eg      jan-1  jan-30   feb-1   feb-28  march-1 march-30

> | party | Debit | Credit | Debit | Credit | Debit | Credit |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | xyz | 0 | 0 | 100 | 200 | 10 | 10 |

> What I am trying to do

> Credit and debit is for each month for e.g jan1 - jan30
> what i want is i want to make new dataframe
> which will have  credit - debit for each month for each party for eg
> for jan month credit - debit for party xyz and feb month etc
>
> I tried to throw iterrows but was unable to do it

```
data_set = {
            "Party": [],
            "Month": [],
            "Total": []
        }
```

> ## Name of dataFrame is new_data_set

```
  for ind, row in new_data_set.iterrows():
        data_set["Particulars"].append(ind)
        data_set["Month"].append("")
        data_set["Total"].append(row["Debit"] - row["Credit"])
```

> not getting desired output

Comment: Is there any ability to edit how the dataframe is created in the first place? Having the data stored in rows, while the columns have repeated names, seems like it adds a lot of complexity

Comment: if you share a sample of the data just like it recommends doing so in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) there is a possibility that someone can help you.